# Replace a String with a String in SpannableString

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

It's possible to replace a String with a String in a SpannableString?

Here is my pseudecode:

```
public SpannableString replaceAll(String oldString, String newString){
        SpannableString result = new SpannableString("");
        /*
        Code to replace all matches of oldString with newString
        */
        return result;
    }
```

The method receives a string as its first parameter, which should be replaced with the string that the method receives as the second parameter. And that as often as this string occurs in the SpannableString.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, as the `SpannableString` is immutable by design.
However, `SpannableStringBuilder` offers capabilities to modify the String.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString

Comment: I know that it is immutable. But can I get the strings and than build a new SpannableString with the replaced content?